# Do free buildings give accumulated victory points?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

Some quests (like *Lure Artisans of Mirabar*), and maybe some intrigue cards, allow you to place a building from *Builder's Hall* into play at no cost. Does the player also score the accumulated victory points (gems)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see why you wouldn't get the gems. The quest on your cards says:

> Put 1 building from Builder's Hall into play and under your control
> at no cost.

The rules for Builder's Hall say:

> Choose one of the face-up Buildings available for purchase and pay
> its Gold cost. You immediately score any VP for that Building and
> place its tile in one of the open spots on the board. Place one of
> your control markers on that tile to show you are the owner. After you
> purchase a Building, immediately draw the top tile of the Building
> stack and place it face-up on the vacated space.

So after paying the gold cost of Zero you would surely take the gems and then fill the vacated space with a new building.  Usually if in a game you don't get something the mission card should state you don't get the gems.

The Lords Of WaterDeep FAQ at BGG also answers this question specifically saying you take the gems.  [BGG game FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Lords_of_Waterdeep_FAQ):

> Q: Does an effect that places a building, or puts a building into play count as buying/purchasing the building?
>
> A: No. You count as having bought a building only if you assign an agent to "Builder's Hall" and pay the gold cost of the building. Putting a building into play by other means (such as by completing the "Lure Artisans of Mirabar" quest) does not count as buying the building. However, if you put a building into play under your control from "Builder's Hall" and that building has any VP tokens on it, you gain those VP's regardless of whether you bought it or simply put it in play.